Nextjs Dockerize deployment using Caprover
I have nextjs app, using nextjs 14.2.1, and I have a CICD pipepline on bitbucket, whenever I run the build locally, my docker.stage works fine and build the app and I am able to compose and view the app at the described host, but when I push to bitbucket and deploy, it keeps breaking and saying
failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 477c9fb1-28c9-4045-a9cc-08a7673e4c97::u2nyjtgnhu6dp1afwar29xnmk: "/app/.next/standalone": not found

But I don't get this error on my local.
This is my docker file
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
# RUN \
#   if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
#   elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
#   elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
#   else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
#   fi

RUN yarn install

RUN yarn add sharp --ignore-engines

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
ENV NEXT_PRIVATE_STANDALONE true
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.

RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn build; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run build; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm run build; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi

  # Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs


# Set the correct permission for prerender cache
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 4000
ENV PORT=4000

# server.js is created by next build from the standalone output
# https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/output
CMD ["node", "server.js"]

I expect the code to build successfully on the pipeline using the nextjs docker file provided on giuthub

Most probably the builder stage is not generating the /app/.next/standalone mentioned in the error message but it is being copied from your local dirty building context with the COPY . . directive. Whatever instruction you did run locally that produced the standalone bundle should also be run in your builder stage.
A clean checkout should help you reproduce the problem. Try git clean -Xdi .
To prevent this kind of bugs, you could have a very severe .dockerignore that whitelists the few paths that your containers actually need from the context, so you could never pollute the images with naive COPY directives.
# .dockerignore
*
!src
!package.json
!yarn.lock*
!package-lock.json*
!pnpm-lock.yaml*

